# KeyboardDateTimePicker Material UI Not null validation

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I have implemented KeyboardDateTimePicker. I am not able to validate it for `empty` or `null` values? I tried few things for validation, yet its not working.

Code:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDateTimePicker
    required={true}
    format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    value={this.props.StartDate}
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
    onChange={(event) => this.props.handleDateTime(event)}
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I tried placing required, validated=true in form control, yet its not working.

Did not find any keywords here :
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker

About DateTimePicker:
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker

If anyone has faced similar issue please suggest.

Comment: add  props `error` and `helperText`
You can make a function like `checkErrors=()=>{return this.props.StartDate?false:true}`
and use props like this:
`error={checkErrors()}
helperText={checkErrors():"Some error message":""}
`

Comment: @kapilpandey : Thanks a lot for the solution. It worked !!

Comment: Awesome,I am posting the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add props `error` and `helperText`

You can make a function `checkErrors=()=>this.props.StartDate?false:true` and use props

```
error={checkErrors()}
helperText={checkErrors():"Some error message":""}
```

Your code may looking something like this:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                      required={true}
                      format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                      value={this.props.StartDate
                      }
                      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleDateTime(event)}
                      error={this.props.StartDate?false:true}
                      helperText={this.props.StartDate?"Some error message":""}
                    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```